# Custom password screen that can't be avoided

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a password screen that is activated only on user demand and cannot be put to background unless the correct password is given.This is for password protecting the device only when the user wants to, instead of having the android password feature that is either constantly enabled or disabled. I've tried two ways so far:

a) with an activity but home button cannot be intercepted for all android versions.

b) with a service that overlays the whole screen  but with this implementation i can't add more than one view  (and i'll need 13 for all the buttons and TextView to show the password as it is written). Putting all the buttons in an xml and making a layout variable and setting this as the view makes the buttons unresponsive.

I know it is possible because Tasker has this option. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: so basically you want a password dialog that can't be cancelled unless correct password is provided?

Comment: Tasker has this option? Are you sure? I think it would be scary if one app or service could take over the screen and essentially render the device useless unless it accepts a password. That'd be ransomware at its finest.

Comment: Rohan Kandwal : Yes that is what I want
323go: Yes Tasker has this feature. It's under Display and its called Lock (not SystemLock which is turning the screen off). And it is not scary. It is the user's decision to use this feature. If the user can't use it properly that's the user's fault. Also a phone restart solves the issue of not knowing the password as this is not a persistant screen.(either will mine)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I find it a pretty interesting question (and non-repetitive)

Comment: propably because most people wear blindfolds and freak out when the subject of windows that can't be close arrises. As if there are no other ways to cause problems if you wanted to. Ad software that is included with most apps and reads personal data is far more dangerous than a password screen that protects the user's device when that is wanted !!!!

Comment: @323go and user3051067:  Tasker's "Lock" does not lock down the whole phone - you can still hit "Home" to send Tasker to the background (or even just hit "cancel" on the lock popup).  All it does is prevent certain Activities/etc from running

Comment: you application needs to be a launcher, and the user must decide to make it default application. Then you probably can proxy the home action to the default launcher when the password is safely entered.

Comment: When Tasker's Lock feature is enabled you CAN hit the home button and it does take you to the home screen...BUT the password screen is still there in front of you so you can't see what is happening in the background. So the phone is still protected.

Comment: @user3051067 Nope, I can use my phone just fine, even with it up in the background.  It only protects Tasker.

Comment: :s In my phone (HTC Sensation) i can't get rid of this screen unless i type the paassword. Are you sure you are using the Lock feature under Display? If yes then i guess it doesn't work for all android versions even for Tasker.

Comment: Yep, the Lock feature under Display.  I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S.  AFAIK, all Tasker's popup is, is a modal dialog - nothing special.  It blocks the UI of the Activity that triggered it, but shouldn't be blocking anything else while it's open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem..I'll write the solution for anyone interested. But use with care!! 
Home button puts your app in it's current state in the background. That includes your activities. So starting the password activity again in the onPause method is useless. But home button press does not affect your services. So....

In the password activity i have a static boolean isRunning variable that is set to true onResume and false onPause(). Also onPause() i start a SERVICE which is allowed as mentioned above. This service shows a fullscreen ImageView in black color so nothing is visible while home screen is active.(Restoring the previous state of your app usually takes a few seconds.)
The service also checks inside a thread for the value of PasswordActivity.isRunning every 200ms and if it is false it attempts to start the password activity. When isRunnning is true the service kills its self and we're back to the password screen. That's it.